# Get link for same page in different language

Tags: 7, uri, i18n-l10n, navigation

I want to display a link to the spanish version of a page in my template, but another module is removing the language option on my link function:

```
l('Visit this page in Spanish', "node/{$node->nid}", array( 'language'=>'es' ));
```

I have the general routing set up the way I want; most of the time I want links to target the current language.  Except this time - now I really want that link in spanish : )

How do I force `l()` to keep the language I specify?  Or should I use another function?

Answer (score 2):

It should work when using this function: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_get_translations/7

This will return all the translations of a given nid, when an ES translation is given you can print your l().

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the tnid
  $tnid = $node->tnid;
  $trans = translation_node_get_translations($tnid);
  print_r($trans);

}
```

And inside $trans array you'll have basic information of all translations (including current language) - title, language, nid, status... But of course, you can use nid to load whole node if you need something more.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as [this one from 2012](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/147219/16495) - any reason to post the same method again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a specific page URL in a specific language URL use this code:

```
$languages = language_list();
$english_page_url = l(t('About'), 'node/22', array('language' => $languages['en']));
$arabic_page_url = l(t('About'), 'node/22', array('language' => $languages['ar']));
```

For your example you can use:

```
$languages = language_list();
l(t('Visit this page in Spanish'), 'node/' . $node->nid, array('language'=> $languages['es']));
```

Because you have to pass the language object not only the language prefix!